# Filter an array of objects against array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

That returns an empty array. I have also tried using the array of `selectedRules[0]` itself but got same result. How can we do the comparison of filter on an array of objects against an array of strings to return an array of objects with each filtered rule?

```
   const allRules = [
      {
       RuleName: "Two",
      RuleId: 2
        },
        {
          RuleName: "Three",
         RuleId: 3
        },
      {
        RuleName: "Four",
        RuleId:4
      }
    ];

    const selectedRules = ["2", "3"]

    const filteredRule = allRules.filter(x => x.RuleId === selectedRules)

    console.log(filteredRule) // []
```

Comment: The question you are asking is not very clear. Please provide steps that you are taking, what is the outcome and what do you expect to happen? Questions should be phrased in such a way that assumes the reader knows nothing about your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- Convert the rules to the same type so that comparison works (a string won't be `===` to a number)
- Check whether the `selectedRules` array `.includes` the `RuleId` value being iterated over:

```js
const allRules = [{
    RuleName: "Two",
    RuleId: 2
  },
  {
    RuleName: "Three",
    RuleId: 3
  },
  {
    RuleName: "Four",
    RuleId: 4
  }
];

const selectedRules = ["2", "3"]

const filteredRule = allRules.filter(x => selectedRules.includes(String(x.RuleId)))

console.log(filteredRule)
```

Comment: Bro what a fk legend u are. Thank you!